# CakePHP Controller Action not Rendering

Tags: php, cakephp, web, frameworks

I have a CakePHP Action that is not rendering it's view, however the action is being executed.

I have the controller VoteTagsController with the action alltags()

```
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');

class VoteTagsController extends AppController {

    public function index(){
        $this->set('allVoteTags', $this->VoteTag->find('all'));
    }

    public function alltags(){
        echo "Running";
        echo "Test";        
    }     
}
```

The view exsists also in /View/VoteTags/alltags.ctp

I am attempting to load the action from http://test_site.dev/votetags/alltags

I've tried everything but cannot get this view to render I just get a white page, no errors.

Changing the name of the controller however and refreshing sends me to an Error Not Found page which indicates the action is being fired but not rendered.

Any ideas?

Comment: try $this->render('alltags');

Comment: http://test_site.dev/vote_tags/alltags ?

Comment: Nothing, just a <h1> tag, neither of the suggestions above worked

Comment: what is the path of the view file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on conventions your URL should be `test_site.dev/vote_tags/alltags`
If you wish to change this you can add to your `app/Config/routes.php` file the following line

`Router::connect('/votetags/alltags', array('controller' => 'vote_tags'))`

Or whatever other url template you might like.
For more information read http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html

Comment: I still seem to have the same issue, should I change the controller name also?

Comment: 1. can you hit the view page via `test_site.dev/vote_tags/alltags` ?
2. do you have debug set to 0?
3. do you have php errors turned off?

Comment: I have errors switched on, and yes I hit the same page but still with no rendering

Comment: you did not state if you have debug set to 0. if your view is not rendering you should be getting some type of message. Where did you put your view file? it should be in app/Views/VoteTags/alltags.ctp